# Reloading Mojolicous server in Windows

Tags: windows, perl, configuration, mojolicious

I have a Mojolicious application running on Windows which uses the plugin `Mojolicious::Plugin::Config` to load a configuration file.

Every time the configuration file is changed I need to restart the server. Is it possible to restart the server automatically whenever the configuration file is changed, without the need to run it again manually?

How can this problem be solved using Mojolicious on Windows?

I know it's possible to do this with `Mojo::Server::Morbo` but i am interested in using the built-in daemon as Morbo is for development.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation recommends that `Mojo::Server::Morbo` should be used only for development work because restarting the server process when a configuration file changes isn't a good idea for live server software. You would normally make and test the changes offline, gather a number of modifications together into a release, and choose a low-traffic time of day to implement the update and restart the live server

However, since an instantaneous restart is exactly your goal, there is no other reason to avoid `Mojo::Server::Morbo`. I would question the wisdom of your approach,  but the facility is available to you to use as you wish

Comment: You can always implement a watcher on the config file that tells the daemon to restart. Morbo might have other consequences. I am not sure if turning off all the debugging is possible, and you probably don't want _trace_ and _info_ level stuff go into your logs in a production environment.